# How to compare bit mask?

Tags: python, binary

I want to create function which return me true when first number (binary) contains in second number (binary):

```
a = '1100'
b = '0101'
```

returns false but:

```
a = '0100'
b = '0101'
```

returns true

How to do it?

Comment: What exactly have you tried so far?

Comment: Why not parse to integers and literally use bitwise operators?

Comment: Questions asking "why isn't this code working?" need to actually show the code which isn't working.

Comment: You are working with string. Try working out with actual binary number, such as:
a = 0b1100

Comment: Do you want to return True only if the first number is contained in the second? Does this mean that if you switch `a` and `b` around in your second example, you want to return False?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by first creating the binary numbers out of the strings, and next, doing an `and (&)` on the numbers and checking if the output matches either of them.

```
In [14]: str_to_bin = lambda x: int(x, 2)
    ...: 
    ...: a = '1100'
    ...: b = '0101'
    ...: a = str_to_bin(a)
    ...: b = str_to_bin(b)
    ...: print a & b in (a, b)
    ...: 
    ...: a = '0100'
    ...: b = '0101'
    ...: a = str_to_bin(a)
    ...: b = str_to_bin(b)
    ...: print a & b in (a, b)
    ...: 
False
True
```

If you want to exclusively check for `a` being present in `b`, use the condition

```
print a & b == a
```

Comment: If one of the numbers is a subset of the other, AND will result to the smaller of the two. It'd be similar to do `c & d == min(c, d)`, not that it matters a lot.

Comment: @Reti43 Well actually, for the case of just 2 integers, `a & b in (a, b)` would perform slightly better than `c & d == min(c, d)` at the nano second level :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension like this:

```
a_list = '1100'
b_list = '0101'

# If a value in a_list is '1', remember if the corresponding value in b_list is '1', too 
[b == '1' for a, b in zip(a_list, b_list) if a == '1']
>> [False, True]
```

and then wrap it in a function whichever way you like:

```
def contains(a_list, b_list):
  comparison = [b == '1' for a, b in zip(a_list, b_list) if a == '1']
  return all(comparison)

contains('1100', '0101')
>> False
contains('0100', '0101')
>> True
```

Comment: Why not simply `all(i<=j for i, j in zip('0100', '0101'))`?

Comment: Yeah, changed it to `all` already. It usually takes me some time to remember python builtins and I start out doing everything by hand. To the `gte` in favor of what I did, I think I prefer my way, but yours is as good. And shorter of course.

Comment: You name the function `contains`, but you actually call `compare()`. More importantly, your method only checks whether the first number is a subset of the second. `compare('0100', '0101')` returns `True`, but `compare('0101', '0100')` returns `False`.

Comment: @Reti43 Whoops, the function name got lost in the fixes. Thanks for pointing it out.
The way I understood OP it was supposed to be unidirectional, so it works as I intended. Also, `contains(a, b) && contains(b, a) -> (a == b)`, which you should then just check instead.